# Show a panel on MapBox in Android

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I use MapBox in Android and show some Points on it. Now I want to show a panel top-left of map and show some information in this panel. How can i do this? (An Example show in image in URL: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/img/directions/gljs-plugin.png , a panel like that panel show in image , the black panel on the left)
Thanks

```
private MapView mapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Mapbox.getInstance(this, YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
        @Override
        public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

            // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add data or make other map adjustments



        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: you must create and feed data yourself

Comment: @Radesh Thank you for your answer. But my question is, how do I put the desired panel on the map?

Comment: The data you're seeing is coming from the Mapbox Directions API https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/directions/#mapbox-directions-api. When it comes to the actual views, there's no implementation ready out of the box, you'll need to build those views yourself.

Comment: @ŁukaszPaczos Thanks for your answer. That's exactly my question, how do I create this view and put it on the map ?!

Comment: If you'd like it to truly be rendered by the map, you can prepare a custom Android View, generate a bitmap out of it and add it to the map on a `SymbolLayer`. Check out this example https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/labs/SymbolLayerMapillaryActivity.java